# cons function does not accept my input

Tags: list, input, racket, cons

Well, I am trying to add two elements to become a list, and [from the video of Prof. Colleen Lewis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ing4IKLW4rU&list=PLHqz-wcqDQIEThNEXViEb1iFh9vbOtUD_&index=3) at minute 4 and 53 secs, and from [the official racket site](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Pairs__Lists__and_Racket_Syntax.html) I saw that the best practice is to use "cons".

When I did:

```
(cons (Listof Number) (Listof (Listof Number)))
```

It worked perfectly well but it gave me a mirror to what I am suppose to get. Therefore I tried:

```
(cons (Listof (Listof Number)) (Listof Number) )
```

This resulted in:

> Type Checker: Polymorphic function `cons' could not be applied to
>   arguments:
>
> Argument 1:
>
> Expected: a
>
> Given:    (Listof (Listof Real))
>
> Argument 2:
>
> Expected: (Listof a)
>
> Given:    (Listof Real)
>
> Result type:     (Listof a)
>
> Expected result: (Listof (Listof Real))
>
> in: (cons acc (get-min&max-from-mixed-list (first lol)))

This is weird, since the [official site](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Pairs__Lists__and_Racket_Syntax.html) says that:

> The cons function actually accepts **any two values**, not just a list
>   for the second argument.

Here is my actual code:

```scm
(: min&max-lists (-> (Listof (Listof Any)) (Listof (Listof Number))))
(: tail-min&max-lists (-> (Listof (Listof Any)) (Listof (Listof Number)) (Listof (Listof Number))))
(: get-min&max-from-mixed-list (-> (Listof Any) (Listof Number)))

(define (min&max-lists lol)
  (tail-min&max-lists lol '()))

(define (tail-min&max-lists lol acc)
  (if (null? lol)
      acc
      (tail-min&max-lists (rest lol) (cons acc (get-min&max-from-mixed-list (first lol))))))

(define (get-min&max-from-mixed-list mixedList)
  (if (null? (sublist-numbers mixedList))
      '()
      (min&maxRec (sublist-numbers mixedList) (first (sublist-numbers mixedList)) (first (sublist-numbers mixedList)))))

(test (min&max-lists '((any "Benny" 10 OP 8) (any "Benny" OP (2 3)))) => '((8 10) ()))
```

Here is the code for all kinds of functions that my code uses.  These work fine, so there should be no reason to check them:

```scm
#lang pl
(require rackunit)
(require racket/trace)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;Question 1

(: min&maxRec (-> (Listof Number) Number Number (Listof Number)))
(: min&max (-> Number Number Number Number Number (Listof Number) ))


(define (min&max number1 number2 number3 number4 number5)              ; gets all numbers and sends to the min&max recursive part
  (min&maxRec (list number2 number3 number4 number5) number1 number1)) ; made all numbers to become a list and has max and min numbers

(define (min&maxRec myList max min)
  ;; logic: 1) if finished list give back result 2) else check if head of list max or min and recall the function with a shorter list and the new max or min
  (if (null? myList)
      ;return the min and max from myList when finished looking at all numbers
      (list min max)
      (if (> (first myList) max); is the head max?
          (min&maxRec (rest myList) (first myList) min) 
          (if (< (first myList) min) ; is the head min?
              (min&maxRec (rest myList) max (first myList) )
              (min&maxRec (rest myList) max min)))))

(test (min&max 2 3 2 7 1) => '(1 7))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;Question 2 a

(: sublist-numbers (-> (Listof Any) (Listof Number)))
(: tail-sublist-numbers (-> (Listof Any) (Listof Number) (Listof Number)))

;;This func calls a diff func since the tail-recursion needs an accumelator.
(define (sublist-numbers myList)    
  (tail-sublist-numbers myList `()))

;;this uses tail-recursion (all calculations are dont before the recursion and are sent with an accumelator)
(define (tail-sublist-numbers myList acc)
  (if (null? myList)
      acc ; if finished all vars in list
      (if (number? (first myList))
          (tail-sublist-numbers (rest myList) (cons (first myList) acc)) ; if the head of list is a number add it to acc, and continue working on the rest of the list
          (tail-sublist-numbers (rest myList) acc))))                    ; else throw this var and work on rest of list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when you link to `cons` in `#lang racket` it is not the same as `cons` in other languages, like `#lang pl`. Same names functions in different languages can be the same but often are they different. Eg. `cons` and friends in `#!r6rs` are mapped from `mcons` and friends in `#lang racket`

I have no idea what `#lang pl` is but it seems like it is typed in some way. I assume that when you say you do:

```
(cons (Listof Number) (Listof (Listof Number)))
```

You mean that you do:

```
(cons a b)
```

Where `a` is of type `(Listof Number)` and `b` is of type `(Listof (Listof Number))`. I notice that the type of the second is Listof whatever was type on the first. In your trial the types don't have that relationship but the other way around. It's likely that you have switched the arguments and that the correct code for the `acc` is:

```
(cons (get-min&max-from-mixed-list (first lol)) acc)
```

I assume type specification of `cons` might require the second list to be lists of the same type as the type of the first argument. For the untyped languages like Scheme and `#lang racket` you can have any type in the two arguments.

```
#lang racket

(cons 3 #f) ; ==> (3 . #f)
```

Comment: Hi, from my understanding pl is suppose to be really similar in "cons" but maybe I am wrong... do you know maybe how to solve this problem?

Comment: @Tomer I've updated my answer. I'm sure you have switched the first and second argument.

Comment: Hey yeah your right when doing "(cons (get-min&max-from-mixed-list (first lol)) acc)" everything works but I get (() '((8 10)) instead of ( '((8 10) ()) therefor I tried to do: "(cons acc (get-min&max-from-mixed-list (first lol)))"

Comment: @Tomer If `(cons 'a '(b)) ; ==> (a b)` gives you the answer in the wrong order then `(cons '(b) 'a) ; ==> ((b) . a)` is not the solution. Doing `reverse` on `acc` in the final step is.